# Testing express UserController with vitest in MERN application

Tags: express, testing, controller, mern, vitest

I am trying to test a UserController and its user registration and I am stuck, since I am new to testing. My test code so far:

```
import { it, expect, describe, vi } from "vitest"
import UserController from '../controllers/user.controller.js'
import User from "../models/User.js"

describe('User Registration', () => {
  it('should register a new user and send a verification email', async () => {
    const req = {
      body: {
        firstName: 'John',
        lastName: 'Doe',
        email: 'johndoe@example.com',
        password: 'password123',
      }
    }

    const res = {
      status: vi.fn().mockImplementation(function (statusCode) {
        this.statusCode = statusCode
        return this
      }),
      json: vi.fn().mockImplementation(function (data) {
        this.data = data
      }),
    }

    const mockSavedUser = {
      _id: '123',
      firstName: 'John',
      lastName: 'Doe',
      email: "test@example.com", 
      password: 'password123',
    }
    await UserController.registerUser(req, res)

    User.findOne = vi.fn().mockResolvedValue(null)
    User.prototype.save = vi.fn().mockResolvedValue(mockSavedUser)
    
    expect(User.findOne).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ email: "test@example.com" })

    console.log(req, res)
    
  })
})
```

I habe two problems with this code:

1. There is a assertion error with the expect(User.findOne) part (expected "spy" to be called with arguments: [ { email: 'test@example.com' } ]). Can anybody explain why?
2. When I console log the res, the object is undefined. It seems that res is never returned. Can somebody explain what I am doing wrong?

Help would be greatly appreciated.
Regards!

This is my UserController code:

```
import User from "../models/User.js"
import { generateVerificationToken, sendVerificationEmail } from "../utils/mail.js"


const UserController = {
  //REGISTER USER
  registerUser (req, res) {
    const { firstName, lastName, email, password } = req.body
    let errorObject = {}

    User.findOne({ email })
      .then(user => {
        // check if user email already exists
        if (user) {
          errorObject = {
            success: false,
            type: "server",
            message: `${user.email} already exists.`
          }
          return res.status(400).json(errorObject)
        }

        const newUser = new User({
          firstName,
          lastName,
          email,
          password,
        })

        // Generate a verification token for the user
        const verificationToken = generateVerificationToken()
        newUser.verificationToken = verificationToken
      
        newUser
          .save()
          .then(() => { 
            // Send a verification email to the user
            sendVerificationEmail(email, verificationToken)
              .then(() => {
                res.status(201).json({ 
                  success: true,
                  message: `${email} created. Verification email sent to ${email}.`
                })
                console.log(res)
                
              })
              .catch(error => {
                const errorObject = {
                  success: false,
                  type: "emailServer", 
                  message: "Error sending verification email. Please retry.", 
                  errorType: error.type
                }
                res.status(500).json(errorObject)
              })
          })
          .catch(error => {
            const errorObject = {
              success: false,
              type: "server", 
              message: `Saving ${email} to the database did not work. Please retry.` 
            }
            res.status(500).json(errorObject)
          })
      })
      .catch(error => {
        const errorObject = {
          success: false,
          type: "server", 
          message: "Server error occurred. Please retry.", 
        }
        res.status(500).json(errorObject)
      })
  }
}
```